# Definitions of "direction"

Tags: meaning, word-difference, terminology

While I was in school we were explained (I think it was a physics class) that:

- "direction" is just a line (infinite) between two points, going either way;
- "sense" is the definite way of traveling, either from A to B, OR from B to A, on a certain direction.

I know that in my language "direction" is used (in everyday speech) to encompass both meanings of "direction" and "sense". **Is that the same in English?**

As example, the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/direction) provides the definition:

> direction = the position towards which someone or something moves or faces

*But I did not find a definition in the restricted sense I mentioned above.*

Comment: I'd say that *just a line between two points, going either way* is a distance.

Comment: "distance" is already another thing, it is the length of the line, not the line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Direction* is, in this context, the orientation someone at the first point would have to be in if they were to be facing the second point.

If you're talking about physics class, I expect the terms would be ***distance*** and ***displacement***. *Distance* is a *scalar quantity*, the length of a line drawn between two points<sup>1</sup>, while *displacement* is a *vector quantity*, giving both the distance and the direction.

Alternatively, you might be talking about the ***orientation*** and ***sense*** of a vector. Taken together, those two properties provide the easier idea of *direction*. The *orientation* of a vector is an undirected idea of its orientation in space - so a north-south line is the same as a south-north line, because if you superimpose them they are indistinguishable. If you say there are two points on the line, and ask which comes 'first', that is the *sense*. Taken together, you have a *direction*. Essentially, a vector is simply a line with magnitude and direction, but that direction can be broken down into the orientation of the vector - up-down, left-right, etc - and the idea of which end of the vector is the 'start'.

I'm not sure there's any free online resources that get into such a technical definition, though.

---

<sup>1</sup>: Some teach that distance is the 'distance covered' even if taking a non-direct route, not travelling by a straight line. If you understand distance in that way, then what I have called 'distance' could be called 'straight line distance'. As I was taught it, *distance* is the length of the straight line, and if you want a term for the length of a wiggly line it would be 'distance travelled'.

Comment: I am surely not talking about distance (straight line, along the road...). I am interested in the meanings: "Along which line?" and "Towards which end of that line.". While entirely correct, I am not sure that this is what I am looking for. I will have to still think about it. Maybe some other answer will bring some different light.

Comment: Okay, I found some more about this... I can see why you might have gotten muddled...

Comment: @virolino: there you go, vector maths explanation. You just got one of the words wrong.

Comment: I am not sure how much "wrong" and how much "false friend", but you are right. The new addition is what I had in mind. Unfortunately, I was not aware enough at the moment to realize that I had to read about vectors. Thank you.